# Python package installed on GCP instance but not showing up when I launch a notebook through Jupiter Lab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

When I launch a notebook in Jupyter Lab running on a GCP AI Platform Notebook, it is not recognizing a package despite having already installed it.

I have installed the package (RDKit) using conda and when I run

```py
import rdkit
```

in a terminal there isn't an issue. However when I open my notebook and try the same line of code I get an error telling me that it can't find the module.

Comment: How did you setup Jupyter Lab? Is this a GCP AI Platform Notebooks or did you set it up yourself?

Comment: Yes it's the GCP AI Platform Notebook.

Comment: Could you please share the exact steps to reproduce this?  E.g. "1. Create an AI Platform Notebook of Tensorflow 1.x type from the UI, 2. Open Jupyter Lab 3. Open a terminal in Jupyter Lab 4. Run command 'xxx' to install rdkit 5. Create a notebook in jupyterlab 6. Run command 'import rdkit'

Answer (score 0):

If you install a new package using the terminal you want to ensure two things:

1. You installed it using the version of Python that matches your notebook kernel (pip vs pip3)
2. You restart your notebook kernel after installing the new package (go to the Notebook -> Kernel -> Restart Kernel)

But there's a better option:

You can make things easier on yourself by installing the package directly from the notebook cell using:
 `%pip install <package_name>`

With this method there is no need to worry about pip vs pip3 (it is automatically taken care of) and no need to restart the kernel either

Comment: Just a heads up, rdkit cannot currently be installed using pip